# PHP Guzzle Basic Auth: Grabbing the bearer token

Tags: php, http-headers, basic-authentication, guzzle, bearer-token

#### Background

Moving an API in postman over to PHP, and using guzzle to do it. I'm mostly self-taught, so I have a few holes in my understanding of HTTP basic authentication. ***The API is working, I just think I'm being a bit redundant here.*** Maybe someone can help clarify?

#### Expected Result

1. I send a request with `user:pass` in the header

   - I receive a token
2. I send a request with `bearer {{token}}` in the header

   - I am authenticated in the API

#### Actual Result

1. I send a request with `user:pass` in the header

   - I am authenticated in the API with no token

#### Question

So what gives? Was I suppose to grab the token and some point, but I didn't? I know postman generated a token for me to use via its basic auth, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it in Guzzle or via Curl.

#### Example Code

> Remember, this code works, but I just can't seem to get back the Bearer token...

**Guzzle Example**

```
public function Test() {

    $this->http_client = new Guzzle([
        'base_uri' => $this->request_url,
        'headers' => [
            'Accept' => 'application/json',
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        ],
    ]);

    $result = $this->http_client->request('GET', 'customers',
        ['auth' => [$this->api_name, $this->api_key]
    ]);

    //$result->getHeader('Authorization'); <-- This doesn't work...

    return $result->getBody();
}
```

**Curl Example**

```
public function Test() {

    $username = $this->api_name;
    $password = $this->api_key;
    $url = $this->request_url . 'customers';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}
```